# Hibernate OneToOne mapping by primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

Given these two entities how do I establish a working OneToOne relationship with Hibernate:

```
public class UserScan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //more fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userScan", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserScanData userScanData;

}

public class UserScanData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_scan_id")
    private Long userScanId;

    //more fields

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_scan_id")
    private UserScan userScan;
}
```

Obviously something is wrong here (I get an error of a missing field), but I'm not sure how to do this. @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn did not work either.

Current error is:

**Schema-validation: missing column [user_scan_id] in table [user_scan]**

I just want to connect the two table inside "UserScan", "UserScanData" does not need to have the reverse relationship (unless needed by hibernate)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code according to your requirements. I left the reverse relation on UserScanData as you had it on your code, in case you want to keep it. If I didn't explain the changes enough feel free to ask :)

```
public class UserScan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //more fields

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_scan_id") //You specify the column in UserScan table that refers to the UserScanData id.
    private UserScanData userScanData;

}

public class UserScanData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_scan_id")
    private Long userScanId;

    //more fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "userScanData", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //This is the reverse relation you may not need
    private UserScan userScan;
}
```